# Rails app not working because each SQL request stuck on "still waiting for AccessShareLock"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, activerecord, migration

After doing a git push to my Heroku server on my rails app, then running a migation (`heroku run rails db:migrate`), for one simple migration that is creating a table :

```
create_table :some_tables do |t|
   t.string :some_field
end
```

But I can't explain why, the migration was stuck, Here the logs :

```
LOG: statement: CREATE TABLE blabla...
LOG: process 12439 still waiting for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 16425 of database 16385 after 1000.102 ms
```

After 2 minutes, I decided to end the process (ctrl+c) (usually it takes some seconds), but it was still running somehow, the next logs are, 20 minutes (!!) after :

```
LOG: process 12439 acquired AccessExclusiveLock on relation 16425 of database 16385 after 1399661.769 ms
LOG: duration: 1399722.492 ms
LOG: could not send data to client: Connection timed out
FATAL: connection to client lost
```

And during this time, my app was down. Here are the logs in the app :

```
 ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError (could not obtain a connection from the pool within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds); all pooled connections were in use)
```

But I think that it was not really an issue with the pool, it is just that the db was completely lock for some reason with the migration.

I retried it a second times, and it is doing it again, but I am able to kill it quickly with `heroku pg:killall`

Comment: OID 16425 looks low enough that this is a system table. Can you verify with: SELECT * FROM pg_class WHERE oid = '16425'; And then find out what is blocking the relation, with: SELECT * FROM pg_locks WHERE relation = '16425';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was time to upgrade my PostgresSQL version (9.3 -> 10) so I decided to upgrade it, and the issue was gone after this.

So I don't know what was exactly the issue... but upgrading the whole db worked for me.